# How do I fix collect2 error while compiling an old MUD?

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, mud

I'm trying to run make on an Ubuntu machine to compile a RoT MUD, but the farthest I've gotten is when I get a `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

This is what comes immediately before the error in the terminal (along with a lot of other similar errors):

```
/usr/bin/ld: obj/wizlist.o:/home/lucas/Projects/R2b5/src/merc.h:3355: multiple definition of `bllmax'; obj/act_comm.o:/home/lucas/Projects/R2b5/src/merc.h:3355: first defined here
```

From what I've gathered this means that the header files have variable declarations in them, and that using `static` is an easy fix, however, I haven't been able to figure out where I should put that keyword in the code to fix this issue. The following is the only mention of `bllmax` in merc.h:

```
int bllmax, crbmax, crnmax, srpmax, mngmax;
```

[Here](http://www.mudbytes.net/files/958/) is the program I'm trying to compile.

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the difference between *declaration* and *definition*. A *declaration* is telling the compiler that the symbol exists *somewhere* but possibly not here. A *definition* is telling the compiler that the symbol exists *here*.

The line you show (without any context) is *defining* the variables, which means they will be defined in each source file that includes the header file.

What it should do is to *declare* the variables, which can be done by making them `extern`:

```
extern int bllmax, crbmax, crnmax, srpmax, mngmax;
```

Then in a *single* source file define the variables (without `extern`).

Comment: Thank you, I got "declaration" and "definition" mixed up, but that still doesn't answer my question. This is old code which was once able to be compiled, so I don't understand why making these definitions `extern` would be necessary. Not only that, but there are about a hundred other definitions in the program, so would I have to add `extern` to each one and then create a source file for them? Also, what other context would you like for the line I provided? It's in a header file called merc.h and defines a variable that is in the error I put in my question.

Comment: @LucasAquinodeAssis It was a long time since I looked through any MERC based source, but isn't there some kind of conditional compilation (`#ifdef` or similar) which puts the definitions in only a single source file? Also note that even if a code-base is publicly and legally available, that doesn't mean it's actually good or even buildable from the get-go. Especially considering that most of them were written a *very* long time ago when compilers might not have been as strict as they are today.

Comment: @LucasAquinodeAssis I've checked the code now, and this is indeed a problem. The only reason this ever worked was probably because the compilers and linkers back then were much more lax. These multiple definitions isn't the only errors, I couldn't even get to the linking stage when attempting to build. If you want to build it you have a lot of work ahead of you.